# Bash script reads from .csv file to insert objects into mongo using --eval, keep getting SyntaxError. Can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, linux, mongodb, bash

Im working on a homework assignment. We have to insert 1000 different users based on male and female. I started with the males. The idea is to use the script to insert all 442 records from a .csv file. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r userName firstName lastName gender dob language bloodType zodiac constellation planet genre dino;
do
        mongo USERNAME --eval  'db.USERNAME.insert({username:"'$userName'",first:"'$firstName'",last:"'$lastName'",gender:"'$gender'",dob:"'$dob'"})'
done < males1.csv
```

I am not inserting all the fields because I am trying to determine the error.
When I deleted the dob part of the code, it suddenly worked. It looked like this:

```
mongo X --eval 'db.USERNAME_male_a5.insert({username:"'$userName'",first:"'$firstName'",last:"'$lastName'",gender:"'$gender'"})'
```

I was able to enter all 442 records. But I was only able to insert the username, firstName lastName and Gender. I need the other fields in there too. But when I added the dob, it was given the following error:

uncaught exception: SyntaxError: "" literal not terminated before end of script :
@(shell eval):1:96

I tried changing the quotes, but then I would get user X is not defined, which further confused me.

My professor gave us this syntax:

```
mongo USERNAME_a5 --eval 'db.USERNAME_{GENDER}_a5.insert({username:"", first:"", last:"", gender:"", dob:"", language:"", blood_type:"", zodiac:"", constellations:"", planets:"", tv_genre:"", dino:""})'
```

But this proved to be difficult to work with as I realized I need to change the quotes so that it doesn't literally insert the word "$userName"

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you know MongoDB offers a tool called `mongoimport` that can read a csv file and insert the documents into the database and collection of your choice?

Comment: @Allen Eney - Which value does `$dob` have then?

Comment: @Joe No, but I do now. Thank you

Comment: @Armali In this case, it would something like 'january 1 1990'

Comment: Can any of the _fields_ be empty?

Comment: No they cannot. Or rather, they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be overlooked with all those quoting characters that the parameter expansion `$dob` is not quoted, so that when `dob` is *something like 'january 1 1990'* the supposed `--eval` parameter is split at the spaces into the three pieces `db.USERNAME.insert({username:"…",first:"…",last:"…",gender:"…",dob:"january`,
`1` and
`1990"})`, which causes the `SyntaxError: "" literal not terminated`. You can correct this by putting double quotes around `$dob` (i. e. `…,dob:"'"$dob"'"})'`) and at least all other variables which can contain spaces.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much @Armali